# populating flexgrid with a file vb6

Tags: vb6, msflexgrid

So I need to put all the names in a file into column 1 on flexgird, each name should go on its own row. here is what I have but i just get "invalid row value"

```
namefile = App.Path & "\names.dat"
Open namefile For Input As #1
While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, x
        With MSFlexGrid1
            .Col = 1
            .Rows = rowcount + 1
            .Text = x
        End With
Wend
End Sub
```

Any help would be fantastic and thanks in advance

Comment: You don't appear to be setting .Row (the current row).  This probably should be set to .Rows - 1.

Also, you could use .TextMatrix (I believe this gives better performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why rowcount is in your example code, but this works for me

```
namefile = App.Path & "\names.dat"
Open namefile For Input As #1
MSFlexGrid1.Rows = 1
MSFlexGrid1.Col = 1
While Not EOF(1)
    Input #1, x
    With MSFlexGrid1
       .Rows = .Rows + 1
       .Row = .Rows - 1
       .Text = x
    End With
Wend
End Sub
```

I've also pulled the `.Col =1` out of your loop - you don't need to keep setting it and your loop will be faster than without it (not by much but repeatedly setting it is pointless)

Answer (score 0):

[How to dump contents of the Recordset into a Flexgrid.](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=50)

Once you load whatever it is into a recordset, this article provides techniques on various things you'll want to do with the grid.